# How to create a Image Dataset just like MNIST dataset?

Tags: python, image-processing, dataset, neural-network, keras

I have 10000 BMP images of some handwritten digits. If i want to feed the datas to a neural network what do i need to do ? For MNIST dataset i just had to write

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

I am using Keras library in python . How can i create such dataset ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can either write a function that loads all your images and stack them into a numpy array if all fits in RAM or use Keras ImageDataGenerator (https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) which includes a function `flow_from_directory`. You can find an example here https://gist.github.com/fchollet/0830affa1f7f19fd47b06d4cf89ed44d.

Comment: It would be better if you wrote the code directly here. The content of the links may be lost with time, especially the Github one. I think it's a best practice to put the whole code instead of links in SO community.

Answer (score 3):

You should write your own function to load all the images or do it like:

```
imagePaths = sorted(list(paths.list_images(args["testset"])))

# loop over the input images
for imagePath in imagePaths:
    # load the image, pre-process it, and store it in the data list
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (IMAGE_DIMS[1], IMAGE_DIMS[0]))
    image = img_to_array(image)
    data.append(image)
    # extract the class label from the image path and update the
    # labels list


data = np.array(data, dtype="float") / 255.0
```

Answer (score 2):

I might be late, but I am posting my answer to help others who visit this question in search of an answer. In this answer, I will be explaining the dataset type, how to generate such datasets, and how to load those files.

***What is the file format***

These datasets are datasets already `vectorized` and in `Numpy format`. Check [here (Keras Datasets Documentation)](https://keras.io/api/datasets/) for the reference. These datasets are stored in `.npz` file format. Check [here(MNIST digits classification dataset)](https://keras.io/api/datasets/mnist/). Here is a code block copied from the documentation for reference.

```py
tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data(path="mnist.npz")
```

Once you generate a .npz file you can use it the way you use the mnist default datasets.

***How to generate a .npz file***

Here is how to generate such a dataset from all the images in a folder

```py
#generate and save file
from PIL import Image
import os
import numpy as np

path_to_files = "./images/"    
vectorized_images = []

for _, file in enumerate(os.listdir(path_to_files)):
    image = Image.open(path_to_files + file)
    image_array = np.array(image)
    vectorized_images.append(image_array)        
# save as DataX or any other name. But the same element name is to be used while loading it back. 
np.savez("./mnistlikedataset.npz",DataX=vectorized_images)
```

if you want to use save more than one element you can do something like this with appropriate other changes to code.

```py
np.savez("./mnistlikedataset.npz",DataX=vectorized_images_x,DataY=vectorized_images_Y)
```

**How to load the data file**

```py
#load and use file
import numpy as np

path = "./mnistlikedataset.npz"
with np.load(path) as data:
    #load DataX as train_data
    train_data = data['DataX']
    print(train_data)
```

Similar to saving multiple elements, if you want to load multiple elements from a file you can do something like this with other appropriate changes

```py
with np.load(path) as data:
    train_data = data['DataX']
    print(train_data)
    test_data = data['DataY']
    print(test_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

numpy can save array to file as binary 
[numpy save](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html)

```
import numpy as np

def save_data():
  [images, labels] = read_data()
  outshape = len(images[0])
  npimages = np.empty((0, outshape), dtype=np.int32)
  nplabels = np.empty((0,), dtype=np.int32)

  for i in range(len(labels)):
      label = labels[i]
      npimages = np.append(npimages, [images[i]], axis=0)
      nplabels = np.append(nplabels, y)

  np.save('images', npimages)
  np.save('labels', nplabels)


def read_data():
  return [np.load('images.npy'), np.load('labels.npy')]
```