# convert a group of images in 'n' folders to dataset (eg: Mnist), to work with CNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset, conv-neural-network, torchaudio

I am trying to convert images generated in to a dataset.
(All I have is just `png` images in `n` folders and there is no label or meta data)

This is what I aspire to do:

1. I am using `torch audio` to convert audio formats to `Mel spectrogram` and save the images as `png` format. Status:done
2. Now I have `n` number of folders(classes) with images so I am curious if I could convert the newly generated images into data and
   target as in normal datasets, so that I can use `sklearn` to do the
   test train splits `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`
   .
   Status:not done

eg: fetch mnist dataset

```
ds_mnist = sklearn.datasets.fetch_openml(
     data_id=554,
     as_frame=False
 )
```

Split data and target in to X and y

```
dataset_X = ds_mnist .data.astype('float32')

dataset_y = ds_mnist .target.astype('int64')
```

Comment: I never do this but I found with Google on `Kaggle`: [DIY MNIST Dataset | Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/code/mikalaichaly/diy-mnist-dataset)

Comment: It seems someone already asked for this on Stackoverflow (in 2016): [python - How to create a Image Dataset just like MNIST dataset? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39289285/how-to-create-a-image-dataset-just-like-mnist-dataset)